# How do I write inline Javascript inside a HTML attribute, inside a PHP string?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open a modal by changing the display property of an element upon clicking a different element. How would I write the following HTML attribute:

```
onclick="document.getElementById(edit).style.display="inline-block"
```

inside a PHP string?

Comment: What "echo statement"?  What is preventing you from writing the code you want to write?  Please show your attempt and explain the problem.

Comment: echo ' onclick="document.getElementById(edit).style.display="inline-block" '; I am trying this but its giving me no action. Modal doesn't opens up.

Comment: Is the echo from PHP? You should make that more clear if so.

Comment: yes the echo is from PHP.@markmoxx

Comment: @josh: Please CLARIFY the problem.  The question makes NO mention of PHP, nor does it show ANY PHP code.  What is the code you've written?  What does it output to the browser (when you view the page source in the browser)?  Are there any errors in your PHP logs?  In the browser's development console?  We only know the information you give us.

Comment: @josh so.. did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP, you should use a backslash to escape the double quotes inside a double-quote string. E.g.

`echo "onclick=\"document.getElementById(edit).style.display='inline-block'\"";`

Notice the single quotes for the inline JavaScript. This makes it easier than using only double quotes, as otherwise you'd have something like:

`echo "onclick=\"document.getElementById(edit).style.display=\\"inline-block\\"\"";`

**Edit:** I also just noticed your getElementById has no quotes around it, you're passing a variable. So, for more fun:

`echo "onclick=\"document.getElementById(\\"edit\\").style.display=\\"inline-block\\"\"";`

or simply:

`echo "onclick='document.getElementById(\"edit\").style.display=\"inline-block\"'";`

...And this is why inlining everything is a bad idea. Define your onClick handlers outside of the element, in a `<script>` block.

You should read up on your string syntax.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax

For Javascript, it's much the same - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Escaping_characters